# regex in R "eats" part of the string

Tags: regex, r, split, stringi

I want to split a character string into two groups. The string's structure is pretty simple, yet I haven't been able to make it work.

```
txt <- "text12-01-2016"
```

It's always some letters, followed by a date, and the date, obviously starts with a number. I've tried the following regex at https://regex101.com/ and effectively get the string properly separated:

```
([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9].*)
1. "text"
2. "12-01-2016"
```

But when I try in R it fails:

```
strsplit(a[1],split = "([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)")
[[1]]
 [1] ""  " " ""  "." " " ""  " " ""  "-" ""  "-" ""
```

And if I introduce double square brackets, then it "eats" out the last character of the first group, and the first of the second:

```
strsplit(txt,split = "([[a-zA-Z]]*)([[0-9]]*)")
[[1]]
[1] "tex"      "2-01-2016"
```

It doesn't matter if I use `perl=TRUE`. Result is consistent also if I use `stringi::stri_split`, so it's a problem in my regex.

What is the correct regex to use in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem" here is that you have a regex for *matching*, not for *splitting*.

You can use the [following PCRE regex](https://regex101.com/r/lW9bW1/2) with `strsplit`:

```
strsplit(txt,split = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl=T)
[[1]]
[1] "text"       "12-01-2016"
```

The regex will match the location between a letter and a digit and strsplit will split the result. You can unlist it further on if you need.

If you want to use your regex, use [`str_match`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/stringr/docs/str_match) from `stringr`:

```
> library(stringr)
>str_match(txt,  "([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9].*)")
     [,1]             [,2]   [,3]        
[1,] "text12-01-2016" "text" "12-01-2016"
```